# Get a float variable given a generic array c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random

I am creating an RPG where weighted spawns are frequently used. Many classes such as monsters, loot or dungeon generation have a variable in them called spawnChance which is a value 0-100 that determiens the spawn rate.

I have previously been using this style of selection to get a random weighted member from an array

```
 var weights = enemy.Select(e => e.spawnChance);
 var index = weights.GetRandomWeightedIndex();
 return enemy[index];
```

Here is the extension

```
 public static int GetRandomWeightedIndex(this IEnumerable<float> weights)
{
    int count = weights.Count();
    if (weights == null || count == 0)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning($"Weights are invalid");

        return -1;
    }
    else if (count == 1)
        return 0;
    float w;
    float t = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        w = weights.ElementAt(i);

        if (float.IsPositiveInfinity(w))
        {
            return i;
        }
        else if (w >= 0f && !float.IsNaN(w))
        {
            t += weights.ElementAt(i); ;
        }
    }

    float r = UnityEngine.Random.value;
    float s = 0f;

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        w = weights.ElementAt(i); ;
        if (float.IsNaN(w) || w <= 0f) continue;

        s += w / t;
        if (s >= r) return i;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

However, i'd like to reduce this code since the method of selecting all floats via linq and then passing it into the extension and then back is rather tedious and used dozens of times.

I thought of using reflection to find a variable called 'spawnChance' inside a generic class, but since everything is generated at runtime that would be quite slow.

Could I possibly turn spawnChance from a simple float into a class, and then somehow write a linq method that will performantly be able to pull that class value out? Due to the project setup the classes cannot inherit from a spawnChance class.
Thoughts? Thanks for your time!

Comment: If I were you I would implement spawn chances not as floating-point numbers, but as integer percentages.  Remember that `float`s in C# are not decimals, but base-2 numbers (specifically binary32 numbers like 0.010101 in binary).  Treating binary numbers like decimals can sometimes lead to surprising results.

Comment: Alternately, C#'s `System.Decimal` (`decimal`) can be used, which _is_ a decimal number format.

Comment: Floating point is fine if you process it correctly, ie, using it as a summated 'distance' rather than discrete measures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define an interface and then have the classes exposing a spawn chance implementing it. It is then easy to test whether an object implements it or not.

```
public interface ISpawnable
{
    float SpawnChance { get; }
}
```

`SpawnChance` must be a property. It is not necessary to declare the setter for this use case (because you only need reading it); however, implementations can still provide one.

Then you can test

```
if (obj is ISpawnable spawnable) {
    float w = spawnable.SpawnChance;
    ...
}
```

Or with LINQ if you have a list of mixed objects

```
var weights = mixedTypeObjects
    .OfType<ISpawnable>()         // Filters objects implementing it and casts to it.
    .Select(x => x.SpawnChance);
```

---

If you have generic types or methods, you can use this interface as generic type constraint.

```
public class SpawnService<T>
    where T : ISpawnable
{ ... }
```

This restricts `T` to be a type implementing `ISpawnable` and allows you to access `SpawnChance` without any casting within this class.

---

Another option is to derive spawnable objects from a common base class exposing a spawn chance. The interface is more flexible since it works for classes deriving from different base classes. This is an advantage if you already have a class hierarchy and you want classes implement it independently from this hierarchy.

---

You can also simply pass game objects to the method and filter and cast inside:

```
public static int GetRandomWeightedIndex(this IEnumerable<GameObjects> gameObjects)
{
    var weights = gameObjects
        .OfType<ISpawnable>()
        .Select(g => g.SpawnChance);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Interface probably isn't ideal but the Generics would be.

Answer (score 0):

See how you go with

```
public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class WeightedItem
    {
        public GameObject Prefab; // Or whatever you're randomising
        public float Weight;
    }

    public WeightedItem[] Items;

    private float TotalWeight;

    public void Start() {
        // If your lists don't change, pre-calc TotalWeight here.
        // If they do change, you'll have to recalculate it when it does.
        TotalWeight = Items.Sum(m => m.Weight);
    }

    public object RandomItem() 
    {
        // Get your 'random' selection.
        var selectionWeight = Random.Range(0, TotalWeight);

        // Parse over the array to find it
        for (var i = 0; i < Items.Length; i++) {
            selectionWeight -= Items[i].Weight;

            if (selectionWeight <= 0)
                return Items[i].Prefab;
        }

        // Should never reach here unless your TotalWeight is wrong
        throw new System.ApplicationException("Randomised Weight exceeded Total Weight!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Modifying this approach worked. It seems interfaces would work but they don't play well with Unity, as they are not exposed in the inspector without workarounds and don't serialize.

Comment: @SkylarStickley There are really only two 'assets' that I always recommend, DOTween and Odin Inspector.  Odin adds a TON of quality-of-life improvements to Inspector display and serialization.  Definitely worth checking out. (Doesn't change this answer, though =)